# Jquery validation for one row out of 5 row

Tags: jquery, validation

i have a form with five table row. so i want to validate that whether one user filled any one row completely.

Here is my code snippet

```
<div class="full_width_structure">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Name :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Designation :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Type :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Contact No</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Address</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name1" class="required[0]" rel="Name" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="designation1" class="required[1]" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="type1">
                    <option>Rural</option>
                    <option>Urban</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="contactnum1" class="required[2] contactno" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name='address1' class="required[3] textarea autoHeightTextarea"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name2" class="" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="designation2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="type2">
                    <option>Rural</option>
                    <option>Urban</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="contactnum2" class="validate[required] text-input"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name='address2' class="validate[required] textarea autoHeightTextarea"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name3" class="validate[required] text-input"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="designation3" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="type3">
                    <option>Rural</option>
                    <option>Urban</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="contactnum3" class="validate[required] text-input"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name='address3' class="validate[required] textarea autoHeightTextarea"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name4" class="validate[required] text-input"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="designation4" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="type4">
                    <option>Rural</option>
                    <option>Urban</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="contactnum4" class="validate[required] text-input"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name='address4' class="validate[required] textarea autoHeightTextarea"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name5" class="validate[required] text-input"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="designation5" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="type5">
                    <option>Rural</option>
                    <option>Urban</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="contactnum5" class="validate[required] text-input"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name='address5' class="validate[required] textarea autoHeightTextarea"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- full_width_structure -->
```

so here one row will have name, designation, type , contact number address.
one user can fill maximum of five entries. because only five static row is exist. so i want to code jquery validation to check whether one user filled one row completely or not.

if he entered one row completely then submit otherwise return false.

My current validation code

```
// not working as expected 

$('#policestationForm input,#policestationForm .autoHeightTextarea').each(function () {
    var thisObj = $(this);
    $(this).focus(function () {
        if (noEmptyExists(thisObj)) {
            if ($(this).val() === 'This Field Required') {
                $(this).val('').removeClass('error_notification');
            }
        } else {
            console.log('no');
        }
    });

    /*
     * Blur 
     */
    $(this).blur(function () {
        if (!noEmptyExists(thisObj)) {
            $(this).addClass('error_notification').val('This Field Required');
            runHideEffect(thisObj);
        } else {

        }
    });
});

/*
 * Submitt form validation 
 */
$('#policestationBtn').submit(function () {
    $('#policestationForm input,#policestationForm      .autoHeightTextarea').each(function () {

    });
});

});

function noEmptyExists(thisObjParam) {
    return $(thisObjParam).filter(function () {
        return !$.trim(this.value);
    }).length === 0;
}

function runHideEffect(thisHideObj) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        thisHideObj.val('').removeClass('error_notification');
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: So what do you have so far in your validation code?

Comment: i have added my current validation code..please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `group validation` for this like,

**HTML**

```
<input class="names" name="name1">
<input class="names" name="name2">
```

**SCRIPT**

**By Validation Plugin**

```
$(function(){
    var vfinc=$("form").validate({
        rules: {
            Name1: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".names"]
            },
            Name2: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".names"]
            }
        },
        groups: {
            group: "Name1 Name2"
        },
    });
});
```

**Simple in Jquery**

This is simply for `names` only you can add for more fields

```
$(function(){
    $('form').on('submit',function(){
        var empty_name=0;
        for(var i=0,len=$('.names').length;i<len;i++)
        {
            nm=$('.names')[i];
            if(nm.value!='')
            {
                empty_name++;
            }
        }
        if(empty_name==0)
        {
            alert('Enter name');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: do i want to use validation jquery..?

Comment: i would like to code simple jquery instead of including external validator plugin